# Add item value to item type in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

I have this object that can have multiple values inside:

```
const [sort, setSort] = useState({
    "city": [],
    "price": [],
    "year": []
});
```

When you click "add", I want "city" to have this value for example: `["Los Angeles"]` or both `["Los Angeles", "New York"]`

How can I do that?

I have tried this but it doesn't work. I'm newbie in javascript/reactjs.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Items() {
    const [sort, setSort] = useState({
        "city": [],
        "price": [],
        "year": []
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(sort);
    }, [sort])


    function addItem(itemType, itemValue)
    {
        for (var type in sort)
        {
            if(type.hasOwnProperty(type))
            {
                if(type.toLowerCase() === itemType.toLowerCase())
                {
                    sort.type.push(itemValue);
                    setSort(sort);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className="item" onClick={(e) => addItem(e, "City", "Los Angeles")}>
                <span>Add LA</span>
            </div>
            <div className="item" onClick={(e) => addItem(e, "City", "New York")}>
                <span>Add NY</span>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Items
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few issues:

1. First, `addItem` should be a callback, so wrap it in the `useCallback` hook.
2. Next, You should use the callback version of `setSort` so that you do not need `sort` as a dependency
3. Finally, you can simplify your state setting logic (ES5/6)

**Note:** You should avoid using `var`; stick with `const` and `let`

```js
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";

const Items = () => {
  const [sort, setSort] = useState({
    city: [],
    price: [],
    year: []
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(sort);
  }, [sort]);

  const addItem = useCallback((_event, itemType, itemValue) => {
    setSort((currentSort) => {
      const key = itemType.toLowerCase(),
        existing = currentSort[key] ?? [];
      return { ...currentSort, [key]: [...existing, itemValue] };
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="item" onClick={(e) => addItem(e, "City", "Los Angeles")}>
        <span>Add LA</span>
      </div>
      <div className="item" onClick={(e) => addItem(e, "City", "New York")}>
        <span>Add NY</span>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Items;
```

Here is a demo of the code above:

```js
const { Fragment, useState, useEffect, useCallback } = React;

const Items = () => {
  const [sort, setSort] = useState({
    city: [],
    price: [],
    year: []
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(sort));
  }, [sort]);

  const addItem = useCallback((_event, itemType, itemValue) => {
    setSort((currentSort) => {
      const key = itemType.toLowerCase(),
        existing = currentSort[key] || [];
      return { ...currentSort, [key]: [...existing, itemValue] };
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="item" onClick={(e) => addItem(e, "City", "Los Angeles")}>
        <span>Add LA</span>
      </div>
      <div className="item" onClick={(e) => addItem(e, "City", "New York")}>
        <span>Add NY</span>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Items />
  </div>
);

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))
  .render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Here is an example of not allowing duplicates. Just use the `Set` object to store the existing array, modify it, and convert it back into an array.

```js
const { Fragment, useState, useEffect, useCallback } = React;

const Items = () => {
  const [sort, setSort] = useState({
    city: [],
    price: [],
    year: []
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(sort));
  }, [sort]);

  const addItem = useCallback((_event, itemType, itemValue) => {
    setSort((currentSort) => {
      const key = itemType.toLowerCase(),
        existing = new Set(currentSort[key] || []);
      existing.add(itemValue);
      return { ...currentSort, [key]: [...existing] };
    });
  }, []);
  
  const removeItem = useCallback((_event, itemType, itemValue) => {
   setSort((currentSort) => {
      const key = itemType.toLowerCase(),
        existing = new Set(currentSort[key] || []);
      existing.delete(itemValue);
      return { ...currentSort, [key]: [...existing] };
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="grid">
      <div className="item" onClick={(e) => addItem(e, "City", "Los Angeles")}>
        <span>Add LA</span>
      </div>
      <div className="item" onClick={(e) => addItem(e, "City", "New York")}>
        <span>Add NY</span>
      </div>
      <div className="item" onClick={(e) => removeItem(e, "City", "Los Angeles")}>
        <span>Remove LA</span>
      </div>
      <div className="item" onClick={(e) => removeItem(e, "City", "New York")}>
        <span>Remove NY</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Items />
  </div>
);

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))
  .render(<App />);
```

```css
html, body, #root {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#root {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  grid-row-gap: 0.5rem;
  grid-column-gap: 2rem;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: That is working very well! One more thing, if I want to make another function to remove a city, how would I do that and also a condition if the city has already been added, to not be add twice?

Comment: @Galbert I added an example utilizing `Set` at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the state value directly. So you need to copy the state, then do changes and then updateState

change this part of code

```
sort.type.push(itemValue);
setSort(sort);
```

To this

```
setSort(oldData => {
    const newData = {...oldData};
    newData[itemType].push(itemValue);

    return newData;
});
```

if you have nested objects, make sure to do deepClone of your object instead of spread operator

Answer (score 0):

This will sort it

```
function Items() {
  const [sort, setSort] = useState({
    city: [],
    price: [],
    year: []
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(sort);
  }, [sort]);


  function addItem(itemType, itemValue) {
    console.log("itemType", itemType, itemValue);
    // check for property
    if (sort?.[itemType] !== undefined) {
      const items = sort?.[itemType];

      if (
        !items.map((e) => e.toLowerCase()).includes(itemValue.toLowerCase())
      ) {
        // creating new array on change
        setSort((s) => {
          return {
            ...s,
            // set updated property
            [itemType]: [...sort?.[itemType], itemValue]
          };
        });
      }
    }
  }

 //Change addItem(e, "City", "Los Angeles") to addItem("city", "Los Angeles")}
  return (
    <>
      <div className="item" onClick={(e) => addItem("city", "Los Angeles")}>
        <span>Add LA</span>
      </div>
      <div className="item" onClick={(e) => addItem("city", "New York")}>
        <span>Add NY</span>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

You can check the new beta docs on how to [work with arrays](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-arrays-in-state#adding-to-an-array)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method maybe to take the existing state from `setSort` and use that to build (using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)) a new object.

```
// Accept the type and value
function addItem(itemType, itemValue) {
  
  // For convenience create a key by lowercasing the type
  const key = itemType.toLowerCase();

  // Take the previous state, and...
  setSort(prev => {

    // ...return a new object by spreading out
    // that previous state, and then using the key to
    // update that array but creating a new one by
    // also spreading out that property into a new array
    // and adding the new value to it
    return {
      ...prev,
      [key]: [ ...prev[key], itemValue ]
    }
  });
}
```

Full example. Note: you don't need to pass the event into the function if you don't use it.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

function Items() {

  const [sort, setSort] = useState({
    city: [],
    price: [],
    year: []
  });

  useEffect(() => console.log(sort), [sort]);

  function addItem(itemType, itemValue) {
    const key = itemType.toLowerCase();
    setSort(prev => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        [key]: [ ...prev[key], itemValue ]
      }
    });
  }

  return (
    <main>
      <div
        className="item"
        onClick={e => addItem("City", "Los Angeles")}>
        <span>Add LA</span>
      </div>
      <div
        className="item"
        onClick={e => addItem("City", "New York")}>
        <span>Add NY</span>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Items />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't change state directly, React.js will not re-render if not use `setState`, When you have a object like that "sort" you could consider use `useReducer`.

Comment: Try adding a sample code thus, your approach might be easily understandable.